# How to Set isEditable and isSelectable for SwiftUI's TextEditor?

Tags: swiftui, appkit

I am looking for equivalents to control the isEditable and isSelectable properties of NSTextView in SwiftUI's TextEditor.

In AppKit, I can easily make a text view editable or selectable using:

```
textView.isEditable = isEditable
textView.isSelectable = isSelectable
```

However, I'm having trouble finding how to achieve similar functionality with a TextEditor in SwiftUI.

Comment: You can't. Just write an `NSViewRepresentable`.

Comment: In SwiftUI you apply `ViewModifier`s that return new `View` you don't access the inner properties of `View` from parents. For disabling selection you can use `.selectionDisabled(isDisabled)` but for editing you would have to create your own modifier.

Answer (score 0):

### Preventing text selection

As of macOS Sonoma 14.3.1, `TextEditor` does **not** honor the [`textSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/textselection(_:)) or [`selectionDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/selectiondisabled(_:)) modifiers. We need to resort to other means:

- Use [`allowsHitTesting(false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/allowshittesting(_:)) to prevent the user from selecting the text with the mouse.
- Use [`focusable(false)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focusable(_:)) to prevent the user from focusing the `TextEditor` by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>.

### Preventing text editing

To prevent text editing, pass a [`Binding.constant`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/constant(_:)) to the `TextEditor`.

### Demo

Use <kbd>tab</kbd> to move focus out of a `TextField`. Use <kbd>⌃tab</kbd> (control-tab) to move focus out of a `TextEditor`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State var text = "hello world"

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("top", text: $text)

            LabeledContent("Editable") {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
            }

            LabeledContent("Selectable") {
                TextEditor(text: .constant(text))
            }

            LabeledContent("Unselectable") {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                    .focusable(false)
            }

            TextField("bottom", text: $text)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    MyView()
        .padding()
}
```